# Does there have to be a specific order to imports when using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import

I was playing around with `matplotlib` for python 2.7 on windows, and I noticed some really strange behavior. I have a small list of imports for my script:

```
import requests
import json
import numpy
import datetime
import time
```

I added `import matplotlib.pyplot` to the end of the list and it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\script\dataTesting.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named urllib.request
```

I don't know what compelled me to to try to move the new import to the top of the list like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import requests
import json
import numpy
import datetime
import time
```

And this time it worked like a charm. Is there some reason it worked the second time with the import at the top of the list and not the first time? Does python need certain imports in certain orders? How can I figure out this order?

Comment: `urllib.request` is not a valid `import` for Python 2, are you sure you're not calling with Python 2 the 1st time and Python 3 the 2nd time?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I am sure. I am actually running it inside of sublimeText. and the default build for my sublime is python 2. I changed the order of the imports as described above and re built it inside of sublime and it worked.

Comment: That is very odd....Did you re-install six inbetween the two times?

Comment: @tacaswell I honestly don't remember if i tried to re-install six between the two tries. there was a point when I thought that was the problem and i do remember trying to re -install six, but I believe that didn't do anything. also the problem still exists. I've gone back and fourth 3 or 4 times moving the import line to the top and bottom. when it is the first line it works perfectly and as the last import statement it breaks with the same error